# UnsatisfiedLinkError with OpenCV and Android

Tags: android, opencv, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I was trying to build a new app using openCV but my app is crashing with not even a single log statement. Then I integrated Crashlytics into my application and it shows the following issue

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for void org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.Canny_3(long, long, double, double) (tried Java_org_opencv_imgproc_Imgproc_Canny_13 and Java_org_opencv_imgproc_Imgproc_Canny_13__JJDD)
       at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.Canny_3(Imgproc.java)
       at org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc.Canny(Imgproc.java:1038)
       at aac.scanner.MainActivity.onCameraFrame(MainActivity.java:72)
       at org.opencv.android.CameraBridgeViewBase.deliverAndDrawFrame(CameraBridgeViewBase.java:392)
       at org.opencv.android.JavaCameraView$CameraWorker.run(JavaCameraView.java:352)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I have also checked other answers on SO like [Android UnsatisfiedLinkError with OpenCV 2.4.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11614227/android-unsatisfiedlinkerror-with-opencv-2-4-2) or [Unsatisfied Link Error - OpenCV for Android Non-native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11939192/unsatisfied-link-error-opencv-for-android-non-native) for this problem and but none of them are working for me.

Since my application project doesn’t have a JNI part, so I had copied the corresponding OpenCV native libs from /sdk/native/libs/ to my project directory to folder main/jniLibs as shown in this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z2vrioEr9OI)

**onResume** method

```
super.onResume();
if (!OpenCVLoader.initDebug()) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Internal OpenCV library not found. Using OpenCV Manager for initialization");
    OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_0_0, this, baseLoaderCallback);
} else {
    Log.d(TAG, "OpenCV library found inside package. Using it!");
    baseLoaderCallback.onManagerConnected(LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS);
}
```

**onCameraFrame** method

```
rgba = inputFrame.rgba();
Imgproc.GaussianBlur(rgba,gray,new Size(5,5),0);
Imgproc.Canny(gray,canny,75,200);
return canny;
```

**BaseLoaderCallback**

```
private BaseLoaderCallback baseLoaderCallback = new BaseLoaderCallback(this) {
    @Override
    public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
        switch (status){
            case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS:
                Log.i(TAG,"onManagerConnected");
                javaCameraView.enableView();
                break;
            default:
                super.onManagerConnected(status);
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

**UPDATE**
Since I was getting `UnsatisfiedLinkError` from running non Native openCV code and none of the solutions of similar posts on SO was working for me. I have wrote all that code in Native openCV code and now my code is running without any error.

Comment: Did you get solution for this error?

Comment: can you post your answer?

Comment: I had wrote all that code in native and everything was working perfectly